# Are all endpoints discontinuous?

Tags: calculus

I learned that something is a limit if the left limit and right limit exist and are equal. But then doesn't this mean that if I have a function  on $[a,b]$, that the endpoints $a$ and $b$ are discontinuous because $a$ doesn't have a left limit and $b$ doesn't have a right limit?

Comment: It depends what you take as your domain. That explanation of limits needing left and right limits is actually a theorem, which is proven based on the assumption that the domain of the function includes an interval around the point of interest. In this case that assumption is not met.

Answer (score 1):

Given $f : A \subset \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, we say that $f$ is continuous at $x_0 \in A $ if for every $\epsilon > 0 $, exists $\delta > 0 $ such that: for all $x \in A$ that $|x - x_0| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$.

The points $x$ considered in the last implication must first of all be in the function's domain. The only possibility in the endpoints $a$ and $b$ are going to $a$ from the right, and going to $b$ from the left. It makes no sense otherwise.

In general, when you have a function $f: A \subset \Bbb R \to \Bbb R $, we only consider limits of $x$ going to *limit points* of $A$, also called *points of accumulation*.

A point $x_0 \in A$ is said a point of accumulation of $A$ if for all $\epsilon > 0$, we have $(]x_0 - \epsilon, x_0 + \epsilon [ \setminus \{x_0\}) \cap A \neq \varnothing $.